# Error when loading .vimrc containing substitution

Tags: vim

How do I map a substitution to a key in my .vimrc without getting an error when I source it?

I'm trying to add

```
nnoremap <leader>re :'<,'>s/<%=*\s//g | '<,'>s/\s-*%>//g
```

to my .vimrc but when I do so and reload the file I get the following error:

[image: The error I see in Vim: Mark not set]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're combining two `:s` commands, but the command separator `|` concludes the `:map` command, so that the second substitution *is executed immediately*, causing the error. You need to escape the `|`, or better use the special `<Bar>` notation inside mappings:

```
nnoremap <leader>re :'<,'>s/<%=*\s//g <Bar> '<,'>s/\s-*%>//g
```

---

PS: Wouldn't it be more natural to define the mapping in visual mode (as it works on the last selection, anyway)? With a `:vmap`, the first `'<,'>` range will be inserted automatically:

```
xnoremap <leader>re :s/<%=*\s//g <Bar> '<,'>s/\s-*%>//g
```

Comment: Fantastic answer Ingo. Correct on both accounts. Thanks a lot!